# svg package failing to work after update

Tags: errors, svg, update

I can't compile the book I've been working on anymore after a general package update. I restricted the issue to a recent version of the `svg` package (Oct. 10). In this MWE:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = it_IT
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{svg}
\setsvg{
  inkscapeexe="C:/Program Files/Inkscape/inkscape.com",
  inkscapearea=nocrop,
 }

\begin{document}
  Hello world!
  \includesvg{crystal}
\end{document}
```

I'm using TeXstudio 2.12.16. When I try to compile the above code I get

```
Process started: lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape "document".tex

Process exited with error(s)
```

with no other info in the Log tab. However, if I check the .log file, I find

```
! error:  (file ./svg-inkscape/"crystal"_svg-tex.pdf) (pdf backend): cannot find
 image file './svg-inkscape/"crystal"_svg-tex.pdf'
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

when the _svg-tex.pdf has actually been created and the PDF file produced, just without the picture. Trying to use `\includeinkscape{crystal_svg-tex.pdf}` is not working either, since I end up with the same messages.

Am I missing something?

Comment: quoting to allow spaces without messing up generated filenames is tricky, could you try the workaround with unquote used here https://github.com/ho-tex/oberdiek/issues/73#issuecomment-543101052  and let me know...

Comment: alternative workaround is `\makeatletter \def\set@curr@file#1{\def\@curr@file{#1}}`

Comment: Thank you, the first solution seems to work in the MWE! Could there be any side effect?

Comment: Edit: it works both in the MWE and in the full text!

Comment: @TeoFed89 created an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/mrpiggi/svg/issues/16
I can not confirm this error with version v2.02c of package svg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest latex release improves the file handling in several ways notably spaces and non-ascii UTF-8 characters are allowed in most contexts. In order to allow spaces web2c TeX implementations allow double quoted strings so `"foo bar.tex"` or even `foo" "bar.svg` etc.

If the filename is just handled by TeX this is easy enough to manage but if (as here) it is passed to a back end pipeline of other applications doing svg to pdf conversions and including files with derived names, making sure the quoting is always in the right place is a bit tricky.

We will iron out any difficulties in the coming days but meanwhile there are a couple of workarounds you can use

1)

```
\makeatletter
\let\quote@name\unquote@name
\makeatother
```

This disables the macro that adds double quotes so you will not get `./svg-inkscape/"crystal"_svg-tex.pdf`  but conversely filenames with spaces will fail, but if you do not hav espaces in your filenames this should be OK.

2)

```
\makeatletter
\def\set@curr@file#1{\def\@curr@file{#1}}
\makeatother
```

This essentially disables all the new filename handling so spaces and UTF-8 protection are both disabled. Again, if you only have ascii filenames this is probably OK.

Both these workarounds affect all filehandling, `\input` and `\usepackage` etc, not just `\includesvg` and `\includegraphics`