# Latex not finding image files, appears they have extra quotes in the name

Tags: graphics, sphinx

Using sphinx-1.8.5 with mactex 2019.  The original rst is

```
.. _cylindricalcapacitorsetupwin:

.. figure:: cylindricalCapacitorSetupWin.png
  :align: center
  :alt: figure 1
  :width: 90%

  Setup Window for the Cylindrical Capacitor example.
```

This gets translated to tex as

```
\noindent\sphinxincludegraphics[width=0.900\linewidth]{{cylindricalCapacitorSetupWin}.png}
```

LaTeX is run via

```
latexmk -pdf -dvi- -ps-  'cylindricalCapacitor.tex'
```

but this fails with

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `"""{cylindricalCapacitorSetupWin}".png' not f
ound: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.144 ...idth]{{cylindricalCapacitorSetupWin}.png}
```

(I notice extra quotes in the filename above.). This worked with mactex 2018, and by hand editing out the extra braces, e.g,

```
{cylindricalCapacitorSetupWin.png}
```

this works with mactex 2019.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: not expected with png actually, but the workarounds here should fix it, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512840/svg-package-failing-to-work-after-update/512877#512877 please reply here if they don't

Comment: Thx.  Appears fixed after updating mactex today.

Comment: are you using `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01>` or `LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1` spurious quotes may be an issue with either but I wouldn't expect the braces to be a problem in patch level 1?

Comment: ah you installed patch level 1 then I guess?

Answer (score -1):

What you need to do is start a new file in a new folder. Then you need to put that picture on that particular folder.

I think this will help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please, can you explain better your solution?